# Using "Office" property of User Profile for search query filter in Content Serch Web Part

Tags: user-profile-property, content-search-web-part

I have a Content Search Web Part where I need to use the Office property of the User Profile. I can get the Department property and use it as filter property but can't get the Office property to select from the filter drop-down. Please see the image.
[image]

Also, is there a way to use custom user profile properties to use for filter in Content Search Web Part?

Any suggestion in the proper direction is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used the New Managed Property in the end. Just created a New Managed property and this property I was able to use for filtering. Don't know if Office property is available by default but using new managed property just did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: you should check the data quality for the "Office" field. It is a text value, usually synced from AD and often the quality is rather poor.
If you will need high quality data I will suggest using the Office Location field which is a managed metadata field

Answer (score -1):

All we need to do is type `{User.name_of_our_property}`

Eg: `Managedproperty:{User.Office}`